# Getting error to install Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, webapi

Getting error to install below reference from nuget package manager in visual studio 2012

> Reference/Package manager - Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth  Error - 
>   Install-Package : 'Newtonsoft.Json' already has a dependency defined
>   for 'NETStandard.Library'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: Did you try to install Visual Studio 19? Maybe it would resolve the issue?

Comment: No. I am using visual studio 2012. Can i use this in VS2012?

Comment: I don't know if you can. But it is very old, so it might cause some compatibility errors. Besides error might come from your project itself, so it would be good if you shared more context about your project.

Comment: I have created new project and try to install/add reference  "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" from package manager. 'Newtonsoft.Json' is already available in project reference folder